# Windows 10 Remote Desktop Connection error, logon failed

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

First time poster after being a long time viewer of other issues to the site. Made multiple searches for a similar issue but came up dry.
anyway, I’ve been using RDP for quite a long time. Yesterday, I decided to wipe my old Windows 10 Pro machine and went about reinstalling 10 Pro as it was. After getting it back to normal, or as it was before the wipe, I wanted to continue working on it from a different PC using RDP. But after enabling RDP on the host and attempting to access it from a different machine I was greeted with a “Logon attempt failed” message.

After several attempts and multiple errors later I decided to update my Microsoft account password as well as perform another wipe of the machine thinking it cached an old account password.
But upon bringing it back to its last state I once again attempted to rdp into the machine and it was back to the same errors.

I’ve since tried creating another user on the machine, or adding another ms account that I use less frequently but I wasn’t successful in logging in with it. I’ve also gone over the account credentials saved in the credential manager going as far as deleting the ms account ones and re-entering new ones. At one point deleting those credentials seemed to unlink my ms account from Microsoft Edge.

I’ve also gone through some other online suggestions of disabling secure connections (or a setting similar in name found in the remote panel) to no success.

All of my testing seems to point to it being related to the ms account in question. Something getting cached onto the windows pc when I link my ms account to it.

If I try RDP into my other PCs, I’m successful using my old password before I reset it about 4 times last night. Old password that’s been used on the account for years.

Before wiping this PC I was able to RDP in normally from any Win 10 Home or Pro machine.

Hoping someone has an idea as to what might be the issue here.

EDIT: I just came across this similar situation but has gone unresolved. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cannot-log-in-my-pc-via-remote-desktop-locally/bca0edd9-1f91-4ea8-b8c6-9749007ac172
Just like this user, my ms account defaults to login with my pin or one of my MFA methods. At no point can I enter a password. I assumed linking to a ms account would pull whatever your current ms account password was and set that as the default.

EDIT2: I tried spinning up another Win10 Pro machine inside of ESXI with a Pro license I wasn't yet using. During that setup process of adding an account to the machine, it oddly asked for a password rather than verifying across the authenticator app/matching numbers in the prompt. I can't recall the last time it's asked me to authenticate in this way tho. But after finishing up the setup on the VM and enabling rdp, I was able to connect to the VM using the last configured MS account password. SMB also works with any of the machines and their originally setup passwords except for the Win10 machine I was originally having issues with.

[RDP Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e79Sw.png)
[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdZAI.png)

Comment: For the system you rebuilt, in Advanced System Properties, did you see Remote Access to allow access?

Comment: Yeah, everything should be setup for remote access. I’ll grab some screenshots and add to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

I also just had the same issue. I think it is related to either using microsoft's authenticator app or using a PIN to login to the system.

I "fixed" my issue by going directly to the machine that I can't RDP into and clicking "forgot my PIN".  It then asks for your Microsoft password.  Once I logged in using the password (instead of the authenticator app), I was then able to RDP into the system.